# Range list for every item in list loop

Tags: python, function, loops, range

I'm trying to create a list of ranges from a flat list of numbers.
It's working when it's looping via simple range but when trying to loop a custom list its giving empty sublists. I just started my python adventure, don't be cruel ;) Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Expected output is from list `[0, 1, 2]` -> `[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]`

```
a = [1,2]
b = []

def makerange(n):
    b.append(list(range(0, n, 1)))

for a in range(10):
    makerange(a)

print(b)

[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: It would be great if you could include the expected output.

Comment: You defined `a` as `[1, 2]`, then throw it away and use `a` as `0` through `9` from a `range`. Did you want it to be based on `[1, 2]`, or `range(10)`? Either way, you need to avoid reusing variable names since it's just going to confuse you; changing the loop variable to `i` (so it's either `for i in range(10):` or `for i in a:`, then `makerange(i)` will be a lot less confusing.

Comment: cannot reproduce: `[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]`

Comment: btw: `b.append(list(range(0, n, 1)))` => `b.append(list(range(n)))`

Comment: Expected output done and the result is now correct

Comment: `for a in range(10)` makes no sense with your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate this:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2]
>>> [list(range(n+1)) for n in a]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Adding 1 to `range` endpoint to include the end value.

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to keep the colleting list inside the function and return it from the function:

```
def multiranges(data):
    rv = []
    for p in data:
        rv.append(list(range(p+1)))
    return rv

print(multiranges([0,1,2]))
```

Output:

```
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing in case your list isn't integers:

- Case 1:

With strings

```
l = [*'ABCDEF']
[l[:n+1] for n in range(len(l))]
```

Output:

```
[['A'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
```

- Case 2:

And with l = [0,1,2]

```
l = [0,1,2]
[l[:n+1] for n in range(len(l))]
```

Output:

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

- Case 3

Or list of integers are in non ascending order:

```
l = [2,1,0]
[l[:n+1] for n in range(len(l))]
```

Output:

```
[[2], [2, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```